# Google map v2 hangs when I click on the zoom button map get hang

Tags: android, json, android-maps-v2

I have a JSON file in which I have around 1800 paths. In 1 path there are several points like a single has.

I have done this code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.golfcart.bean.VillagesListBean;
import com.golfcart.utils.JSONParser;
import com.golfcart.utils.UtilFunction;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MyNavigationGolfcart extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    double sourcelat, sourcelng, destlat, destlng;
    private String result1;
    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mynav);
        addMap();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getPath();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void getPath() {
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                    .open("finalpath.txt")));
            String strLine = null;
            String s = "";
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s + strLine;
            }
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);

            if (json != null) {
                JSONArray features = json.getJSONArray("features");
                for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = features.getJSONObject(i);

                    //                  Log.e("i"+i,"s"+obj.getJSONObject("geometry"));
                    if (obj.getJSONObject("geometry").getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("LineString")) {

                        final JSONArray array = obj.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONArray("coordinates");

                        if (array != null && array.length() > 0) {

                            MyNavigationGolfcart.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (flag) {
                                        try {
                                            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(array.getJSONArray(0).getDouble(1), array.getJSONArray(0).getDouble(0)), 12));
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        flag = false;
                                    }
                                    for (int z = 0; z < array.length() - 1; z++) {

                                        try {
                                            googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                                    .add(new LatLng(array.getJSONArray(z).getDouble(1), array.getJSONArray(z).getDouble(0)), new LatLng(array.getJSONArray(z + 1).getDouble(1), array.getJSONArray(z + 1).getDouble(0)))
                                                    .width(8)
                                                    .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void addMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            //          GoogleMapOptions googleMapsOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
            //          googleMapsOptions.zOrderOnTop( true );
            //          MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(googleMapsOptions);
            //          mapFragment.getMap();
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (googleMap != null) {
                //              googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I did initially I add the map using `addmap()` then I get the JSON from the file in which I have 1800 paths.

Then I took a path and draw on map using `polyline`. I am not getting what is wrong in my code.

Comment: What is the output, are there any crashes ?

Comment: @3amoura map gets hang..

Comment: did you try adding just one path instead of all of them ?

Comment: @3amoura yes I tried and when i add one path it works fine

Comment: Try to parse all the json and get all the polyline , in the background thread , and after finishing parsing return to main thread and add all the polylines

Comment: @3amoura As you said.. I have tried but not working..

Comment: Does it hang for a while then start response again or it crashes ?

Comment: @3amoura It hangs for 20 sec after get giving message. Application nis not responding. Do you want to close it..

Comment: use a asyntask and in do in background download ur json and in onPost method update ur map using the json results so it will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all the **LatLng** Points to **PolyLineOptions** in the *for loop* then add this **PolyLineOptions** just once to the **map**

```
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
    List<LatLng> totalLanLngPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    for (int z = 0; z < array.length() - 1; z++) {
         try {
            totalLanLngPoints.add(new LatLng(array.getJSONArray(z).getDouble(1), array.getJSONArray(z).getDouble(0));
            totalLanLngPoints.add(new LatLng(array.getJSONArray(z + 1).getDouble(1), array.getJSONArray(z + 1).getDouble(0));
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }


                    polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(Color.BLUE).addAll(totalLanLngPoints).geodesic(true);
                    googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

you can also make adding the *For Lopp* which adds the points to the **PolyLineOptions** in your *thread*, and put just the last line which adds the points to **PolyLineOptions** to the map in *onUIThread* Method

Comment: addPolyline(polylineOptions); for the map is called once and filling the polylineoptions list is in the background thread ??